# How to use inline easing with ScrollTo plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, easing

I try to use [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.no/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plug-in with some easing effect.

And I don't want to include [easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) plug-in file, because I will use only once and only one easing effect.

This 'easeOutBack' I want to use :

```
easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
}
```

And my scrollTo's function code like..

```
$(window).scrollTo(element,800,{offset:-80,onAfter:function(){
            alert('done');
}});
```

So I try to insert a easing effect like...

```
$(window).scrollTo(element,800,{offset:-80,
easing:function(x, t, b, c, d){
    return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
},
onAfter:function(){
    alert('done');
}});
```

It dosn't work.

> TypeError: b.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: It's not even 2kb. Do you really want to make things uglier or more complicated to save about two kilobytes?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Agree, But If I still want to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply store the easing function in `$.easing`:

```
$.easing.easeOutBack = function(x, t, b, c, d, s) {
    if(s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * ((s + 1) * t + s) + 1) + b;
};
```

After that you can use it just like you would do when the easing plugin is loaded.

Passing the function directly doesn't work because jQuery's [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) only accepts a string for the easing function (which is looked up in `$.easing`).

Comment: So I cant just put easing function inside my code like that ?

Comment: Correct. The reason for that is probably that people would end up creating a horrible copypasta mess when using the same easing multiple times...

Comment: Thanks so much :D , So back to the basic.. Include the Easing file.